# notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't work with my custom adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I've created a simple `RecyclerView.Adapter` and it displays the content properly, but when I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it - it doesn't work.

**PastEventFragment**

```
public class PastEventFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private List<PastEventItem> mPastEventItemList;
    private PastEventAdapter mPastEventAdapter;

    public PastEventFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View pastEvent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_past_event, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) pastEvent.findViewById(R.id.pe_rv);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mPastEventItemList = PastEventItem.listAll(PastEventItem.class);
        mPastEventAdapter = new PastEventAdapter(mPastEventItemList, getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPastEventAdapter);

        return pastEvent;
    }

    public void refreshAdapter() {
        mPastEventItemList.clear();
        mPastEventItemList = PastEventItem.listAll(PastEventItem.class);
        mPastEventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }



}
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class PastEventAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PastEventAdapter.PastEventHolder> {

    private List<PastEventItem> pastEventItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public PastEventAdapter(List<PastEventItem> pastEventItemList, Context context) {
        this.pastEventItemList = pastEventItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pastEventItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PastEventHolder pastEventHolder, int i) {
        PastEventItem pei = pastEventItemList.get(i);
        switch (pei.type) {
            case 1:
                pastEventHolder.type.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.string1));
                break;
            case 2:
                pastEventHolder.type.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.string2));
                break;
            case 3:
                pastEventHolder.type.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.string3));
                break;
            case 4:
                pastEventHolder.type.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.string4));
                break;
        }

        pastEventHolder.ml.setText(Integer.toString(pei.ml));
        pastEventHolder.per.setText(Integer.toString(pei.per));
    }

    @Override
    public PastEventHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.past_event_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new PastEventHolder(itemView);
    }


    public static class PastEventHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView type;
        private TextView ml;
        private TextView per;

        public PastEventHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pe_type);
            ml = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pe_ml);
            per = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pe_per);
        }
    }
}
```

I call `refreshAdapter` method from another `Fragment` (`DialogFragment`) through an Activity, using `Interface`. I used a debugger, so I know that the `refreshAdapter` method is called. It just has no impact on the RecyclerView which is displayed. When I leave the `PastEventFragment` and then switch back to it, so that the `onCreateView` method is called, all previously added items are shown, so there is no problem with the ORM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your adapter has a reference to `mPastEventItemList`. However, you are creating a new List (a new reference) in this line of code:

```
mPastEventItemList = PastEventItem.listAll(PastEventItem.class);
```

but your adapter is still connected to the old reference of  `mPastEventItemList`.

So you should do something like that instead:

```
 public void refreshAdapter() {
        mPastEventItemList.clear();
        mPastEventItemList.addAll(PastEventItem.listAll(PastEventItem.class));
        mPastEventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `setItemList()` method in the adapter. And set the updated list data using this method with the adapter, after this, call the notifyDatasetChange method